# Update document field from value in another field

Tags: mongodb

I need to do a one-time bulk update and set `signupDate` for a collection for fields that don't have it to be `reminders[0].start` which is a date that these documents do have.  Document may look like:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("545147655ce9ec369b8fa9bf"),
  "reminder" : [{
    "start" : ISODate("2014-11-01T04:00:00Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("545147401f60bac766304334")
  }],
}
```

So for this document I would need `signupDate` to be `ISODate("2014-11-01T04:00:00Z")`.

I could write a node.js script to find documents that don't have `signupDate` and update them individually, but it would be nice to write a single query from the shell.

I see that there is a [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) method I think would look a bit like:

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: {signupDate: {$exists:false}},
    update: {signupDate: "?"}
});
```

Just not sure how to get the value of `reminders[0].start` for the same document if that's even possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field this is a common complaint about mongodb. You can vote for a method to solve this here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-458